# Usage of logging mechanism with slf4 or log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I did some research and found out sfl4j with logback is better than log4j. However, my question is: how do find out which class and method got executed using slf4j? Is it possible to print(log) the class name and method names to a file when a method is called?

Answer (score 3):

You need to put all logback configuration in `logback.xml` file.

One part of that config specifies the format of the messages being logged. By default, you get both the class and method automatically logged with each message.

Please refer to [logback's documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

slf4j just passes the log message along to the logging back end. If you want execution-point logging, you configure it for the backend, whether log4j, logback, or something else.

Comment: I am trying to find it on Google for about half an hour now. Could you please show an example of execution-point-logging